# Store data temporarily for a none logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to store data per user without any form of login system.

The user clicks an item and this item is attributed towards them (like a shopping cart, but these aren't products and nothing is sold). So the user can browse different items then basically add them to cart, effectively. I want it to work like a traditional session would, only not using a session. I read that this is discouraged in Wordpress.

What's the best way to achieve something like this in Wordpress then? Is the Transients API appropriate for this task? Or some other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transients API is of no benefit to you for this particular purpose. They'd have to be specific to each user and soon enough your options table would be huge.

You need to set a cookie instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Since I want to set Cookies on click, I am using JavaScript and this seems to work fine. Using PHP to control the cookies was my first thought but I can't do this efficiently with on-click functionality. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS (or better, jQuery) to call PHP script using ajax/post/get internal jQuery functions and then set a cookie using PHP.